# Content Managemnt System for Flash?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, content-management-system, flash

I'm looking to develop some CMS-able 100% Flash based websites. I have only worked with creating static based Flash websites in the past. What is the best way the approach this?

Answer (score 2):

woah... woah. Does the CMS run in Flash?
if not, that's probably a good thing.

I would recommend you have a CMS system that you can make calls to that will spit out XML
i.e. site.com/data?blogarticleID=7
site.com/data?blogarticlesStartDate=010109&blogarticlesEndDate=whenever

and then you would get a big XML file with all your data inside.  You could then rip this up and stick the data into seperate dynamic textfields....

I would start (because I *did* start) with reading in txt files, use loadvars etc. before you move onto XMLs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to reinvent the wheel, or create a new product. But there is a Free Software (GPL) solution available: [Silex](http://silex-ria.org)

Answer (score 0):

I would say sit with your team and make an analysis on the requirements. Flex with ZendAMF would be so cool, and it would make your work and task very simpler.

Try to go with XML first reading the info, then go with PHP and finally intergate with ZendAMF which will make the application rocking with more options.

Answer (score 0):

If you're Flash sites are going to be backended by XML files, [Verb](http://docs.verbcms.com/vid_flash) integrates very well.